# How do you include padding in an element so that the height and width is the same?

Tags: css

How do you include padding in an element so that the height and width is the same?

Comment: This is a very poor question. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and write better ones in the future. 
I can only guess, that you are perhaps looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing …?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you mean, but you could set height and widht to zero and just add some padding:

```
#elem{
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   padding: 10px;
};
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put this property to your element:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }*

 // * = all elements
```

It is what you were searching?